# Cambiar la imagen de previsualización de todas las filas según su id con Javasript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hola tengo el siguiente script , quiero que me cambie la imagen de previsualización del 3 id de dicha fila, el primero si lo cambia, pero el tercero no, y es el mismo script, para el input.
Pego el código, con depuración y el formu para que veáis que es lo que quiero hacer.

La idea es que cambie la bandera , pero no la cambia en cambio el primer id si que me lo cambia es raro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4 my-3">
     <i class="fa fa-flag form-icons-modales" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <input type="file" name="idioma" class="custom-modal-imagenes" <?php echo 
        $fila_contactos['idioma']; ?> onchange="vista_idioma(event)"><div>
        <img id="img-idioma" src="../subida_de_archivos/<?php echo $fila_contactos['idioma'];?>">
    </div>
 </div>
```

```
let vista_idioma = (event) => {
    let leer_img = new FileReader();
    let id_img = document.getElementById('img-idioma');
    leer_img.onload = () => {
        if (leer_img.readyState == 2) {
            id_img.src = leer_img.result
        }
    }
    leer_img.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0])
    console.log(leer_img);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola David, eh ejecutado el código que has pasado y si funciona, el error es en tu maquina local o en el servidor??

Comment: en la maquina local tiene algo que ver ?

Comment: Hola, a veces cuando esta en el servidor el manejo de rutas es diferente, pero si es en tu  local no deberías tener problemas el problema debe ser o líneas arriba o abajo, porque esa porción de código si te cambia la imagen.

Comment: Hola, en cambio en otros apartados de la aplicación cambiándole las variables y todo y no cambia dicha imagen no se a que se debe, seguiré investigando gracias !